# Is there a way to adjust video quality using android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

So i have a simple app which is supposed to display live stream in m3u8 format. I did by using android MediaPlayer class. I also created custom controller and so far it is working pretty fine.

Now i would like to make my video quality adjustable to current internet connection. I am not sure how mediaPlayer works in this field is it able to do it automatically, or there is no way to actually handle it?

If there is no possibility to solve this problem and stream will be lagging when inernet connection is weak, is there somethink else i can use to handle it?

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: For a better playback control, you might think ExoPlayer, see https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: are you sure that your video is converted in different qualities (480p, 720p, 1080p, etc)? MediaPlayer can't convert video quelity, and for sure can't do that defore accessing the video (downloading the video over the internet)